# Force HTTPS Through HTACCESS With Subdomain Exception

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, https, subdomain

I'm looking to force HTTPS on my entire site except for a subdomain which I am using for a forum. I have an SSL certificate installed on the root domain, but not this forum subdomain. (http://forum.domain.com)

Here is the code for forcing HTTPS:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

However, this also forces HTTPS on subdomains, which effectively makes the forum inaccessible.

How can I create an exception rule for this subdomain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude subdomain, you can use a negitive RewriteCond

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.